# How to do query in Membase?

Tags: nosql, memcached, couchdb, membase

Any **API** for this?

What about query with conditions on key or values ?

I know there is a tap.py, which can dump all contents from Membase, but it it just a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this do this Membase, but Couchbase 2.0 will add query support and will be released in late October. In the meantime you can download a developer preview on the Couchbase website to check out the new features.

Comment: Thanks. Would you share more detailed info about query that is going to be added to Couchbase 2.0?

Comment: The query language will be very similar in syntax to CouchDB querying. You can read more about it here: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views.html